# The ACTIVE selector in the Tab control is finding active child elements of the tab-pane during activation which breaks the tab navigation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I am using bootstrap v-4. I first noticed this when using bootstrap-select version 13 with inside of a tabbed navigation. I narrowed it down to the Tab control finding the active page link in the bootstrap-select "active" and updating it rather than the tab navigation.

Here is a JSFiddle with a small tabbed navigation with pagination(ven it too has a active class in child) in each of the tabs.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrda8vjq/7/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Home</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Messages</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Steps:

- Loads with Home tab active
- Click Profile which loads fine
- Click Messages, and notice that the Profile tab is not hidden, and it shows Profile and Messages.

may I get any Reason for this behavior as well as Quickfix or workaround solution?

thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrda8vjq/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not enclose the **Profile** tab into the corresponding **li**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.0/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Home</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Messages</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. Indeed you are using bootstrap 4 beta wile I use bootstrap 4. Your updated [fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/nrda8vjq/24/)

Comment: damn I forgot that

Comment: bootstrap beta has this issue. they solved this and published with bootstrap-4.